# Noob question on the rules of summation, Law of large numbers

Tags: asymptotics, regression

apologies for what might be a dumb question. I'm studying the law of large numbers, and I'm stuck on the following math

[image]

Why do we need to make it $\frac{1}{n^2}$when pulling it out of the summation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Because for all $a\in\mathbb R$ and random variable $X$, $\operatorname{var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{var}(X)$, which is straightforward from the definition of $\operatorname{var}$.